how do i manipulate my object with its own properties
Currently learning JS, im a beginner.
I created an object to tinker with, and i want to give it some properties that are dependent on th previous properties of the same object.
I have managed to solve it by working about it yet, i know, i am sure there is a way to do it with in the object definition.
please help me, as a beginner i don't know what key words to used when googling so this is my best bet.
By doing this :

airMax1 = {
    price : 200,
    appreciation : 8,
    taxRate : 0.2,
    realPrice : ((this.price+this.appreciation)*this.taxRate)+this.price+this.appreciation,
}
console.log(airMax1)

console.log(airMax1.realPrice)

i was expecting this output :
 { price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2, realPrice: 249.6 } 249.6
yet what i get is this :
{ price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2, realPrice: NaN }
NaN

but when i do it differently like this :
airMax1 = {
    price : 200,
    appreciation : 8,
    taxRate : 0.2,
}

airMax1.realPrice=((airMax1.price+airMax1.appreciation)*airMax1.taxRate)+airMax1.price+airMax1.appreciation

console.log(airMax1)

console.log(airMax1.realPrice)

it works and gives me the disered output of
{ price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2, realPrice: 249.6 }
249.6

how can the same math formula produce a number when its outside the object and not produce a number when its inside the object.
i have swapped the object name with the this. method and all

In your first example, the expression assigned to realPrice gets evaluated before the object has been created, so things like this.price have not yet been set and can't be used in the expression. In general, an object definition shouldn't refer to its own properties because the order in which the properties are created is indeterminate.

You can create a factory that produces augmented objects by using a helper function to dynamically add computed properties.


const addComputedProperty = (receiver, name, getter) => {
  Object.defineProperty(receiver, name, {
    get: getter.bind(receiver),
    enumerable: true // Ensure the property is visible
  });
};

const ProductFactory = {
  create({ price, appreciation, taxRate }) {
    const product = { price, appreciation, taxRate };
    
    addComputedProperty(product, 'realPrice', function() {
      return ((this.price + this.appreciation) * this.taxRate) + 
             this.price + this.appreciation;
    });

    return product;
  }
};

const airMax1 = ProductFactory.create({ price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2 });

console.log(airMax1); // { price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2, realPrice: 249.6 }
console.log(airMax1.realPrice); // 249.6



Here is an alternative that takes an object that defines the computed properties.


const addComputedProperties = (receiver, properties) => {
  Object.entries(properties).forEach(([name, getter]) => {
    Object.defineProperty(receiver, name, {
      get: getter.bind(receiver),
      enumerable: true // Ensure the property is visible
    });
  });
};

const ProductFactory = {
  create({ price, appreciation, taxRate }) {
    const product = { price, appreciation, taxRate };

    addComputedProperties(product, {
      realPrice: function() {
        return ((this.price + this.appreciation) * this.taxRate) +
               this.price + this.appreciation;
      },
    });

    return product;
  }
};

const airMax1 = ProductFactory.create({ price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2 });

console.log(airMax1); // { price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2, realPrice: 249.6 }
console.log(airMax1.realPrice); // 249.6



Finally, here is a much smaller version that augments directly:


// Same as `addComputedProperties`, but just renamed and returns itself
const AugmentObject = (receiver, properties) =>
  Object.entries(properties).reduce((obj, [name, getter]) =>
    Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
      get: getter.bind(obj),
      enumerable: true // Ensure the property is visible
    }), receiver);


const airMax1 = AugmentObject({
  price: 200,
  appreciation: 8,
  taxRate: 0.2
}, {
  realPrice: function() {
    return ((this.price + this.appreciation) * this.taxRate) + 
           this.price + this.appreciation;
  }
});

console.log(airMax1); // { price: 200, appreciation: 8, taxRate: 0.2, realPrice: 249.6 }
console.log(airMax1.realPrice); // 249.6



